# Basic JSF: is it possible to SET a property value in EL?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, seam, ajax4jsf

I need to do something like this:

```
<a4j:support even="onclick" action="#{myBean.myProperty = null}"/>
```

I would like to know if this is possible and which would be the proper syntax if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running an EL 2.2 capable container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc and newer, with a `web.xml` declared conform at least Servlet 3.0), or are using [JBoss EL](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/elenhancements.html) (your `seam` tag suggests that you *are* using it...), then you should be able to invoke methods with arguments in EL:

```
<a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{myBean.setMyProperty(null)}"/>
```

An alternative is using [`<f:setPropertyActionListener>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/setPropertyActionListener.html), this is supported in JSF 1.2 as well:

```
<a4j:support event="onclick" />
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.myProperty}" value="#{null}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Bean setter methods are called on form submission but based on your example why not do something like:

```
<a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{myBean.resetMyProperty}"/>
```

And in your bean your resetMyProperty method would set the myProperty to null